# Help Understanding the Field Trace

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

$\textbf{No}$ full answers please!

I've been working on a class problem for several days now, and I'm completely stuck, mainly because I feel like there's too few assumptions given in the problem statement. Here's the problem for context.

Let $K_{/F}$ be a finite extension of subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $G = \text{Aut}_{F}K$.  Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n$ be all of the distinct embedding of $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that fix elements of $F$. For $\alpha \in K$, define $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(\alpha)$.

a) For $\alpha \in K$, let $f = X^m + f_{m-1}X^{m-1}+\dots+f_0 \in F[X]$ be the monic irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.  Prove that $\text{Tr}_{F(\alpha)/F} (\alpha) = -f_{m-1}$.

b) Show that $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha) \in F$.

c) Express $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha)$ in terms of the coefficients of $f$.

So the first thing that strikes me as weird is that this definition of the trace doesn't seem to align with any definition in other textbooks.  For an arbitrary algebraic extension $K_{/F}$, they define $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha) = [K:F(\alpha)] \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(\alpha)$, the only exception being that $K_{/F}$ is Galois, in which case each $\sigma_i \in \text{Gal}(K_{/F})$, and $\text{Tr}_{K/F}(\alpha) = \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Gal(K/F})} \sigma_i(\alpha)$.

The problem is that $K/F$ need not be Galois.  If $K/F$ was normal, then this would actually work, as since the prime subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, we conclude that $\text{Char}(F)=0$, and so $K/F$ would be Galois.

The second issue is that since $K/F$ isn't necessarily Galois, I don't know how to prove b), which would otherwise be a 3 line proof.

Comment: Observe that the $\sigma_i$s are not $F$-automorphisms of $K$. For example when $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $K=\root3\of2$, we have $\sigma_j(\root3\of2)=\omega^j\root3\of2$ for all $j=1,2,3$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. I haven't (re)checked everything, but one way to tie these superficially different definitions together is to go via a normal closure $N$. That is a finite extension $N/K/F$ such that $N/F$ is Galois.  Then all the $\sigma_i$s can be extended to automorphisms of $N$ in $[N:K]$ distinct ways, and you are on your way.

Comment: By the way, I think the claim in a) is only true, when $K=F(\alpha)$. Consider the case $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2)$, $\alpha=1+\sqrt2$.

Comment: If $N/K/F$ as above, then for all $\alpha\in K$ we get $tr_{N/F}(\alpha)=[N:K] tr_{K/F}(\alpha)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How does one show that the number of ways to extend $\sigma_i$ is $[N:K]$?  I thought this was only true by the fundamental theorem if $N/K$ was also Galois, so that the Galois group was normal?

Comment: What im getting at is $\text{Gal}(K/F) \cong \text{Gal}(N/F) / \text{Gal}(N/K)$, and the order of this quotient group is $[N:F] / [N:K]$, which is the number of distinct $F$ automorphism of $K$ extendable to $N$.

Comment: If $N/F$ is Galois then $N/K$ is automatically also Galois, but $F/K$ is Galois if and only if $Gal(N/K)$ is a normal subgroup of $Gal(N/F)$.

Comment: Anyway, there are $[N:F]$ $F$-automorphisms of $N$ as $G=Gal(N/F)$ has order $[N:F]$. Every left coset of $H=Gal(N/K)$ has the same restriction to $K$.

Comment: That leads to $[K:F]$ different $F$-embeddings of $K$ into $N$ (not all share the same subfield of $N$ as the image). So we must have found all the $\sigma_i$s as restrictions of automorphisms of $N$.

Comment: The case $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $K=F(\root3\of2)$, $N=K(\omega)$ is, again, an illuminating example. $N$ has six different $F$-automorphisms. $H=Gal(N/K)$ is generated by complex conjugation. The left cosets of $H$ correspond to the three different embeddings $K\to N$. So each of those three embeddings has two distinct extensions to $N$, differing from each other by precomposing by complex conjugation.